# Is projection of a measurable subset in product $\sigma$-algebra onto a component space measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, product-space

$(\Omega_i, \mathcal{F}_i), i \in I$ are measurable spaces. $\prod_{i \in I} \mathcal{F}_i$ is the product $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{F}_i, i \in I$.

For any $A \in \prod_{i \in I} \mathcal{F}_i$ and $k \in I$, is $\{\omega_k \in \Omega_k: \exists \omega_i \in I/\{k\},  (\omega_i)_{i \in I} \in A\}$ measurable relative to $\mathcal{F}_k$? If not, how about when $I$ is countable or finite?

For any $A \in \prod_{i \in I} \Omega_i$, if its projection onto any component space defined as above is measurable, will $A \in \prod_{i\in I} \mathcal{F}_i$?

Thanks!

---

Added: For any $A \in \prod_{i \in I} \Omega_i$, if all of its sections onto the component spaces are measurable, will $A \in \prod_{i\in I} \mathcal{F}_i$?
A section of $A$ determined by $(\omega_i)_{i \in I/\{k\}}$ is defined as $\{\omega_k \in \Omega_k: (\omega_i)_{i \in I} \in A \}$.

Comment: For the first question, see the discussion here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34142/projection-of-borel-set-from-r2-to-r1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to the second question is "no". Take $\Omega_1=\Omega_2=\{0,1\}$ and let ${\cal F}_1=\{\emptyset,\{0\},\{1\},\{0,1\}\}$ and ${\cal F}_2=\{\emptyset,\{0,1\}\}$.
The diagonal in $\Omega_1\times\Omega_2$ is not measurable with respect to the product $\sigma$-algebra ${\cal F}_1\times {\cal F}_2$, but its projection either way is the whole space.

Comment: Byron: Thanks! What is "the diagonal in $\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2$?

Comment: The diagonal is $\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$.

Comment: Thanks! What about "for any $A \in \prod_{i \in I} \Omega_i$, if all of its sections onto the component spaces are measurable, will $A \in \prod_{i\in I} \mathcal{F}_i$?" A section of $A$ determined by $(\omega_i)_{i \in I/\{k\}}$ is defined as $\{\omega_k \in \Omega_k: (\omega_i)_{i \in I} \in A \}$.

Comment: Again, no. See Gerald Edgar's answer here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/72922/are-metrics-borel-measurable-functions

Answer (score 4):

**The  answer  to  Ethan's Question 1 is no.**
I
n descriptive set theory, a subset  $A$ of a Polish space  $X$ is an analytic set if it is a continuous image of a Polish space. These sets were first defined by Luzin (1917) and his student Souslin (1917)(see, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_set ).

We  need  well known facts  from the descriptive set theory.

**Fact 1.** The following conditions on a subset $A$  of a Polish space $X$  are equivalent:

(a)  $A$  is analytic;

(b)  There is a Polish space  $Y$  and a Borel set  $B \subseteq  X \times Y$  such that $A$ is projection of $B$., that  is $A=\{ x \in X | (\exists  y)(x,y) \in B\}$.

**Fact  2.**  There exists  an analytic  set  $A_0$ in a Polish space $X$ which is not  Borel.

Let  $A_0$ becomes from  Fact 2. For   $A_0$, the condition  (b)  of  Fact  1  implies that    there  exists   a Polish  space  $Y_0$   and  a  Borel  set  $B_0 \subset  X \times  Y_0  $  such that  $A_0=\{ x \in X | (\exists  y)(x,y) \in B\}$.   Obviously, $B_0$ stands an example  of  Borel subset  of $X \times Y_0$  whose projection on $X$  is  a non-Borel  set $A_0$.
\medskip

**The  answer  to Ethan's Question 2 is no.**  Let  $Y$ be a non-Borel  subset  of  $[0.1]$.

Let consider a set

$C:=([0,1]\times [0,1]) \setminus  ((\{1/2\}\times Y)  \cup (Y \times \{1/2\}))$.

Then  its projection onto any component space defined as above is Borel measurable(more precisely, coincides  with   corresponding component space)  but   $C$  is not  Borel  measurable.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to the first question is no in general. Let $V\subset\mathbb{R}$ be non-Lebesgue measurable and $W\subset\mathbb{R}$ of measure zero. Then $A=V\times W\subset\mathbb{R^2}$ is Lebesgue measurable in $\mathbb{R^2}$ (since has outer measure $0$ and Lebesgue measure is complete), and the projection of $A$ on the first component of $\mathbb{R^2}$ is $V$.

### Edit

As noted in the comments, Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R^2}$ is not the product of Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$, but its completion. So the answer above is not correct.

Comment: Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the product $\sigma$-algebra of Borel $\sigma$-algebras on $\mathbb{R}$. Is Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^2$ the product $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebras on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Does that example really work? I mean: in the question no measures are involved and the product $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measure is *not* the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra on the product and I don't see how you can conclude that your set is measurable with respect to the product $\sigma$-algebra. I think one has to work a bit harder to come up with a counterexample. See [analytic sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_set)

Comment: @Ethan I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Remark  on Julián Aguirre example.**

Let $\cal{F}_i$ be the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable subsets of $R$ for $i=1,2$.

If  $V \subset R$ is  non-Lebesgue measurable and 
$ W \subset R$ is of measure zero, then $A =V \times W \subset R^2$ is not measurable with respect to the product of $\sigma$-algebras $(\cal{F}_i)_{1 \le i \le 2}$. Indeed,  assume the contrary. For $x \in W$, we have $B:= R \times \{x\} \in \cal{F}_1 \times \cal{F}_2$ which (under our assumption) implies that  $A \cap B \in \cal{F}_1 \times \cal{F}_2$, but $A\cap B = V \times \{x\} $ and we claim that $A \cap B$  is not element of the $\sigma$-algebra $\cal{F}_1 \times \cal{F}_2$. This is a contradiction.

Julián Aguirre's  set  $V \times W$ belongs to the $\sigma$-algebra $\cal{F}(R^2)$ of Lebesgue measurable
subsets of $R^2$ but it does not belong the $\sigma$-algebra $\cal{F}_1 \times \cal{F}_2$.
Hence the product of Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebras differs from the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable subsets of the product space.

Thus the answer to the  **Ethan's Question 3** is no.