# Projection of sets in product $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

I'd like some help in an exercise that asks to show by an example that given two $\sigma$-algebras, the projection of a set in the product $\sigma$-algebra need not to be in the corresponding $\sigma$-algebra.

Is there any simple example of that? I only managed to realize that if the set is countable, then the projection has to be in the corresponding $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: The third answer on http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78628/is-projection-of-a-measurable-subset-in-product-sigma-algebra-onto-a-componen?answertab=active#tab-top might be useful to you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I wonder if there is a more elementary example.

Answer (score 0):

consider the lebesgue $\sigma$-Algebra on $\mathbb{R},\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})$ and the product $\sigma$-Algebra $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})$.

Now take a set $A \not\in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})$ and consider $A \times \{0\}$.

Then $A \times \{0\} \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})$ but the projection is A

Comment: Are you sure $A \times \{0\} \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})$? Note that $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}) \neq \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^2)$; the second is the completion of the first.